# OAuth sample app crashes with verifyerror

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to run the sample auth that comes bundled in the play services extras with the android sdk. However, it keeps on crashing no matter what I try.

```
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012): java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/android/gms/auth/sample/helloauth/GetNameInBackground
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.sample.helloauth.HelloActivity.getTask(HelloActivity.java:187)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.sample.helloauth.HelloActivity.access$5(HelloActivity.java:182)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.sample.helloauth.HelloActivity$3.onClick(HelloActivity.java:173)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
05-27 22:52:15.985: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by doing the following things. I hope it resolves the issue for you:

- Go to project properties for the sample project -> Java Build Path -> Order And Export. Make sure everything is checked here and press ok.
- Clean all projects in your workspace.

This worked for me.

Comment: Yes, "Android Private Libraries" has to be checked, because that's where the play-serivces jar lies